# How do I clear the terminal screen down from my cursor position?

Tags: go, ansi-escape

In nodejs, I can clear my screen down with `<WriteStream>.clearScreenDown()`, i.e., `process.stdout.clearScreenDown()`.

How would I achieve this in go?

I assume I need an ansi escape code, but I can not find any for this problem.

I have tried `\033[2J`, but the clears the entire screen. I only want to clear the screen down from my current cursor position.

```golang
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("?")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\033[2J` was the right start, just need to replace the 2 with a 0.

```golang
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Print("\033[0J")
}
```